# Visual Studio 2017 x64 Environment Issues

Tags: windows, visual-studio, dll, environment-variables

**Background**:
I've been tasked with generating a DLL (x64) the can be distributed and incorporated by someone building a Windows application. Now I'm generally a Linux/Unix guy, so some of this has been pulling my hair out. So I installed VS 2017 Community, and got to work.

**Problem**:
I've now wasted 2 days attempting to fix the super helpful error that VS gives me:

> Unhandled Exception: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load
>   file or assembly
>   'C:\workspace\dll_test\bin\x64\Release\netcoreapp2.0\dll_test.dll'. An
>   attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

I've attempted x86/x64/AnyCPU as far as target platforms, clean, rebuild, no success.

**Solution**:
So being more comfortable in a command line environment, I used a script to start the VS Command Line with the proper (x64) environment via, and run the "x64 Visual Studio Command Line":

```
CALL "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" amd64
```

From within this environment I can manually run:

```
csc -out:app.exe Program.cs
```

This results in a ***WORKING*** app.exe that I can execute and happily run from anywhere.

**Question**:
What would cause the VS IDE to fail, with all target platforms, yetthe CMD line environment to work properly? My only assumption is environment variables being setup by the "CALL" script, that aren't being setup properly in VS IDE. ***If that's the case, how can I narrow down what the differences are?*** I don't mind using the CmdLine, but most others I know that work in VS will not like this solution. Any input is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: This is only going to add to your confusion, but the environment variables you set up are for C++ builds, and your C# compile wasn't changed.

Comment: BadImageFormatException means you mix 32 and 64 bit files.

Comment: @magicandre1981 I thought so as well through my google-fu, but no matter the target platform it fails like I stated.

Comment: @Ben Voigt , Would you mind elaborating a bit on your statement?

Comment: "C:\workspace\dll_test\bin\x64\Release\netcoreapp2.0\dll_test.dll" means you created a x64 lib, so if you create an app, target this app also as x64

Comment: @magicandre1981 "I've attempted x86/x64/AnyCPU as far as target platforms, clean, rebuild, no success."

Comment: you created a .net core application. what you want is normal .net framework application that is an exe.

Comment: Not sure what/how, but I just created a new project from scratch, copies over code exactly, and copied over DLL... everything works fine in IDE?

Comment: The bitness of the process is determined by the EXE you start, not by this DLL.  So a simple failure mode is using the wrong flavor of dotnet.exe, or whatever other EXE you used to exercise this DLL.  The failure mode you avoided by having csc.exe build an EXE directly.   Which is not actually a .netcore assembly, using the command line doesn't help much either.  Everything that could possibly go wrong did go wrong :)

Comment: AnyCPU is in general the proper selection for a DLL project.  Works on any processor, can't go wrong like this.

Comment: So I found a solution, see my answer below. Was because I moved the project, and it didn't have the "Directory.Build.targets" to actually assist in the platform targeting... I suck

Answer (score 0):

So I finally figured this out. I started a new project, copied all code & DLLs over, and everything worked fine from the start. This got me thinking, maybe it's not environment variables, but instead the directory structure of WHERE the solutions were being opened.

Sure enough, this all stems from the fact that I MOVED the project from the original directory VS created it in.

**Solution**:
Located "*Directory.Build.targets*" that I found one directory up from my default "repos" directory in the VS build path, and threw it one directory up from my project's current directory, which contains:

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup 
      Condition="'$(OS)' == 'Windows_NT' and
                 '$(TargetFrameworkIdentifier)' == '.NETCoreApp' and
                 '$(SelfContained)' != 'true'"
                  >
    <RunCommand Condition="'$(PlatformTarget)' == 'x86'">$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\dotnet\dotnet</RunCommand>
    <RunCommand Condition="'$(PlatformTarget)' == 'x64'">$(ProgramW6432)\dotnet\dotnet</RunCommand>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Everything runs smooth as butter now... So yes it was indeed a x86/x64 conflict, just not the same solution as everyone else with this problem has run into. Hopefully this helps someone in the future save a bit of time.